# Get gridviedw cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

can anyone tell me  how to get the value of desired cell in a column in gridview ?

this doesnt seem to work:

```
string idc = gvInfo.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

can anyone help me for this? I know this is very basic but It seems that I haven't found anything useful so far.

here's my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" EmptyDataText="Sorry, No Results Found. Enter User again." Visible="true" />
```

Comment: Show your grid. If you use `TemplateFields` you have to use `((TextBox)gvInfo.SelectedRow.FindControl("ControlID")).Text` (presuming it's a `TextBox`).

Comment: I have updated my question. I dont use templatefield sir